# NSPredicate Search Keyboard Lag

Tags: keyboard, nspredicate, lag

I'm experiencing some keyboard lag on my NSPredicate search:

[image: laggy keyboard]

some code:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(head beginswith[c] %@) OR (pro beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValue beginswith[c] %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];

    searchResults = [chengduhua filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

&&&&

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;

}
```

edit: I'm also experiencing serious lag on "cancel" (the "x" on the far right of the search bar when text has been entered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are performing operations in SearchDisplay delegate that are taking time.

You should check size of `searchResults`

```
searchResults = [chengduhua filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

try limiting the results.

Comment: I added an edit above - saying: edit: I'm also experiencing serious lag on "cancel" (the "x" on the far right of the search bar when text has been entered).

Comment: you should show more of your code. try using instruments to figure out what is taking time.

Comment: You should learn to use [instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)